# Windows Mobile 6 CPU architectures?

Tags: windows-mobile, cpu-architecture

Does windows Mobile 6 run on multiple processor architectures? Or is it just ARM generation X? I'm asking because I want to know whether I can compile a native binary program for it and be sure that it runs on all Windows Mobile 6 devices.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be difficult to find definitive information, but the information I can find so far points to Windows Mobile 6 supporting only ARM processors.

First, the [Getting Memory Status and Processor Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158599.aspx) page has the following to say about obtaining system information:

> All devices running Pocket PC 2002 and
>   Smartphone 2002 software and later are
>   based on the ARM4 CPU, and the
>   `wProcessorArchitecture` structure
>   member reports
>   `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM`.

Second, the [Mobile Device Hardware Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158549.aspx) page says the following about the processor:

> **CPU.** Windows Mobile powered devices
>   use the ARM family of CPUs. The ARM
>   processors offer an excellent
>   combination of high performance and
>   low power consumption.

That's about the only references I was able to find on the processor architecture supported on Windows Mobile 6, so it could be that only processors of the ARM architecture is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Mobile 6 only works with ARMv4i processors

Windows Mobile 5 only works with ARMv4 processors.

The confusion comes as both are built on top of Windows CE 5, whihc supports multiple processors architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile support for only ARMv4 kindof means that multiple processor i not a likely option.

Whenever the Windows Mobile version for CE 6 is released may see a turnaround in this.  I would hope Microsoft brings up the minimum requried version of ARM with better multiple processor support.

I know that some phone manufactors are looking into multiple processor support, but I beleave we are still a long way off from seeing them in the wild.

Yes, you can assume that compiling for ARMv4i will mean that it runs on all windows mobile devices.  It does for the applications I write.  If you target WM5 it will run on WM5 - WM6.5 for now.

Comment: The CE 6.0 OS doesn't support multiple processors, so moving to 6.0 wouldn't enable anything new in that area.

Comment: I just read a comment that 'Cashmere' (next CE 6 release) will have symmetric multiprocessing support. http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=2880&tag=nl.e539